# React JS in VSCode Error but code run well, Update useState using sliced object key

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6

I got problem when set state React JS, using sliced Object Key. I got warning in VSCode but code run well. Could you help me to fix it?

Check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ3ub.png

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const key = e.target.name.split('.');

    if(key.length < 2){
        setFormState({
            ...formState,
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        });
    }else{
        setFormState({
            ...formState,
            [key[0]] : {
                ...formState.[key[0]],   /* I got problem with this line */
                [key[2]] : e.target.value
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The dot before your opening square bracket is invalid syntax. You can either access a property of an object by using square brackets or dot notation, not both combined. In this case you should simply remove the `.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you don't need `...formState.[key[0]]` that bracket represents array index so fixed should look like `...formState[key[0]]`